# What is '>' in ubuntu terminal

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-14.04

I sometimes type a command and in haste if I do this

```
pwd\
>
```

I see `>`. What feature is this in linux terminal?

Comment: This is not about programming, it's better to ask this kind of question on https://askubuntu.com/ for example.

Answer (score 2):

It's indicating that the command you've typed is not complete, and it's still waiting for the rest of it.